# To perform insert operation in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, c, insert, function-definition

What is wrong with this code and where is the problem?
I ran this code many times but it's showing that the code is running but I am not getting any output.
Can you tell me where is the mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_arr(int *arr, int n)
{    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int insert_ele(int *arr_a, int *arr_b, int n, int Key)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0, j=0; i<n; i++, j++)
    {
        if(arr_a[i]>Key)
        {
            arr_b[j] = Key;
            arr_b[j+1] = arr_a[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr_b[j] = arr_a[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    //code
    int arr_a[] = {12, 16, 20, 40, 50, 70};
    int arr_b[10];
    int Key = 26;
    int n = sizeof(arr_a)/sizeof(arr_a[0]);
    int indx = insert_ele(arr_a, arr_b, n, Key);
    print_arr(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger. If you step thru the code line by line surely you can find out much more than you have already described. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: When asking questions, please do post compilable code. That snippet doesn't even compile. What's `arr` in `print_arr`?

Comment: One problem is a buffer overflow: `for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)` -> `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`

Comment: Problem is once you encountered condition to insert `Key`, you don't want to insert `Key` again for next elements. You can prevent it by using boolean variable to check if `Key` already inserted or otherwise you can set Key value to `(unsigned int)-1` which is max value of integer to prevent entry again.

Comment: @kaylum `i<=n` is correct because an element was inserted. OP probably meant to pass `arr_b` to `print_arr` which should have `n+1` elements.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo in this statement

```
print_arr(arr, n);
```

It seems you mean

```
print_arr( arr_b, n + 1 );
```

The return type `int` of the function `print_arr` does not make a sense and is useless.

The first parameter of the function should have the qualifier `const` because the passed array is not being changed within the function.

The second parameter should have the type `size_t`.

This for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
```

can invoke undefined behavior if the user of the function will pass the number of elements in the array in the second parameter `n` because in this case there will be an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

Again the return type `int` of the function `insert_ele` does not make a sense and is useless.

The first parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the source array is not being changed within the function. The parameter `n` should have the type `size_t`.

The function has a logical error.

Let's assume that the value of the variable `Key` is less than values of all elements of the array `arr_a`.

In this case the index j will be incremented twice and as a result you will have

```
b[0] = Key; b[2] = Key; b[4] = Key; and so on.
```

The logic of the function will be much clear if to split the for loop in two for loops.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t insert_ele( const int *a, size_t n, int *b, int key )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    for ( ; i < n && !( key < a[i] ); i++ )
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    
    b[i] = key;
    
    for ( ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        b[i+1] = a[i];
    }
    
    return i;
}

FILE *  print_arr( const int *a, size_t n, FILE *fp )
{   
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 12, 16, 20, 40, 50, 70 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    int b[10];
    
    int key = 26;
    
    size_t m = insert_ele( a, N, b, key );
    
    fputc( '\n', print_arr( b, m, stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
12 16 20 26 40 50
```